# How to describe "object" arguments in jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

```
// My function does X and Y.
// @params {object} parameters An object containing the parameters
// @params {function} callback The callback function
function(parameters, callback) {
}
```

But how do I describe how the parameters object should be structured? For example it should be something like:

```
{
  setting1 : 123, // (required, integer)
  setting2 : 'asdf' // (optional, string)
}
```

Answer (score 601, accepted):

From the [@param wiki page](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html):

---

### Parameters With Properties

If a parameter is expected to have a particular property, you can document that immediately after the @param tag for that parameter, like so:

```
 /**
  * @param userInfo Information about the user.
  * @param userInfo.name The name of the user.
  * @param userInfo.email The email of the user.
  */
 function logIn(userInfo) {
        doLogIn(userInfo.name, userInfo.email);
 }
```

---

There used to be a @config tag which immediately followed the corresponding @param, but it appears to have been deprecated ([example here](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/DocExamples)).

Comment: unfortunately the returns tag does not seem to have an equivalent http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagReturns

Comment: In this similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14820610/3094399 they also added @param {Object} options in the beginning. Guess it might be redundant though.

Comment: any idea how to document a object member which is option ? I mean my user object should have username, and can have full name. so how do I specify that full name is optional

Comment: UPDATE: you need to make the `@param userInfo` become `@param {object} useInfo` . Then all the properties will show up in intelligence. Just needs to know it's an object so it can infer the rest of the properties are on it

Answer (score 434):

By now there are 4 different ways to document objects as parameters/types. Each has its own uses. Only 3 of them can be used to document return values, though.

**For objects with a known set of properties (Variant A)**

```
/**
 * @param {{a: number, b: string, c}} myObj description
 */
```

This syntax is ideal for objects that are used only as parameters for this function and don't require further description of each property.
It [can be used for `@returns` as well](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1045).

**For objects with a known set of properties (Variant B)**

Very useful is the [parameters with properties](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties) syntax:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} myObj description
 * @param {number} myObj.a description
 * @param {string} myObj.b description
 * @param {} myObj.c description
 */
```

This syntax is ideal for objects that are used only as parameters for this function and that require further description of each property.
This can not be used for `@returns`.

**For objects that will be used at more than one point in source**

In this case a [@typedef](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) comes in very handy. You can define the type at one point in your source and use it as a type for `@param` or `@returns` or other JSDoc tags that can make use of a type.

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Person
 * @property {string} name how the person is called
 * @property {number} age how many years the person lived
 */
```

You can then use this in a `@param` tag:

```
/**
 * @param {Person} p - Description of p
 */
```

Or in a `@returns`:

```
/**
 * @returns {Person} Description
 */
```

**For objects whose values are all the same type**

```
/**
 * @param {Object.<string, number>} dict
 */
```

The first type (string) documents the type of the keys which in JavaScript is always a string or at least will always be coerced to a string. The second type (number) is the type of the value; this can be any type.
This syntax can be used for `@returns` as well.

**Resources**

Useful information about documenting types can be found here:

https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html

**PS:**

to document an optional value you can use `[]`:

```
/**
 * @param {number} [opt_number] this number is optional
 */
```

or:

```
/**
 * @param {number|undefined} opt_number this number is optional
 */
```

Comment: Does the variant 1 work with multiple types of a property? Like `{{dir: A|B|C }}`?

Comment: Any type annotation should be possible here, so yes

Comment: And for objects whose keys are dynamically generated? Like `{[myVariable]: string}`

Comment: vscode (1.51 below) can't handle @typedef well, it can't show object property for hints, so far I stick with param {Object}

Comment: vscode is working correctly now for the @typedef approach.

Comment: this is valid and working in vscode

Comment: Unfortunately, in my vscode (1.71), the variant-B doesn't show the descripts of the properties in the tooltips (mouse hovering) but only the property names. But the auto-completion shows all the descriptions. The variant-C doesn't even show the property names at all.

Comment: It works to specify an optional property with `[]` surround the property name.

Comment: this is such a well put together answer! thank you.

Answer (score 153):

I see that there is already an answer about the @return tag, but I want to give more details about it.

First of all, the official JSDoc 3 documentation doesn't give us any examples about the @return for a custom object. Please see https://jsdoc.app/tags-returns.html. Now, let's see what we can do until some standard will appear.

- Function returns object where keys are dynamically generated. Example: `{1: 'Pete', 2: 'Mary', 3: 'John'}`. Usually, we iterate over this object with the help of `for(var key in obj){...}`.

  Possible JSDoc according to https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml#JsTypes

  ```
  /**
   * @return {Object.<number, string>}
   */
  function getTmpObject() {
      var result = {}
      for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
          result[i * 3] = 'someValue' + i;
      }
      return result
  }
  ```
- Function returns object where keys are known constants. Example: `{id: 1, title: 'Hello world', type: 'LEARN', children: {...}}`. We can easily access properties of this object: `object.id`.

  Possible JSDoc according to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsdoc-users/TMvUedK9tC4

  - Fake It.

    ```
    /**
     * Generate a point.
     *
     * @returns {Object} point - The point generated by the factory.
     * @returns {number} point.x - The x coordinate.
     * @returns {number} point.y - The y coordinate.
     */
    var pointFactory = function (x, y) {
        return {
            x:x,
            y:y
        }
    }
    ```
  - The Full Monty.

    ```
    /**
     @class generatedPoint
     @private
     @type {Object}
     @property {number} x The x coordinate.
     @property {number} y The y coordinate.
     */
    function generatedPoint(x, y) {
        return {
            x:x,
            y:y
        };
    }

    /**
     * Generate a point.
     *
     * @returns {generatedPoint} The point generated by the factory.
     */

    var pointFactory = function (x, y) {
        return new generatedPoint(x, y);
    }
    ```
  - Define a type.

    ```
    /**
     @typedef generatedPoint
     @type {Object}
     @property {number} x The x coordinate.
     @property {number} y The y coordinate.
     */


    /**
     * Generate a point.
     *
     * @returns {generatedPoint} The point generated by the factory.
     */

    var pointFactory = function (x, y) {
        return {
            x:x,
            y:y
        }
    }
    ```

  According to https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml#JsTypes

  - The record type.

    ```
    /**
     * @return {{myNum: number, myObject}}
     * An anonymous type with the given type members.
     */
    function getTmpObject() {
        return {
            myNum: 2,
            myObject: 0 || undefined || {}
        }
    }
    ```

Answer (score 22):

For `@return` tag use `{{field1: Number, field2: String}}`, see: http://wiki.servoy.com/display/public/DOCS/Annotating+JavaScript+using+JSDoc

Comment: The original link doesn't go anywhere useful. I believe the new version of it is here: https://wiki.servoy.com/display/Serv7/Annotating+JavaScript+Using+JSDoc

Answer (score 19):

If a parameter is expected to have a specific property, you can document that property by providing an additional `@param` tag. For example, if an employee parameter is expected to have name and department properties, you can document it as follows:

```
/**
 * Assign the project to a list of employees.
 * @param {Object[]} employees - The employees who are responsible for the project.
 * @param {string} employees[].name - The name of an employee.
 * @param {string} employees[].department - The employee's department.
 */
function(employees) {
    // ...
}
```

If a parameter is destructured without an explicit name, you can give the object an appropriate one and document its properties.

```
/**
 * Assign the project to an employee.
 * @param {Object} employee - The employee who is responsible for the project.
 * @param {string} employee.name - The name of the employee.
 * @param {string} employee.department - The employee's department.
 */
Project.prototype.assign = function({ name, department }) {
    // ...
};
```

Source: [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties)

Answer (score 0):

There's a new `@config` tag for these cases. They link to the preceding `@param`.

```
/** My function does X and Y.
    @params {object} parameters An object containing the parameters
    @config {integer} setting1 A required setting.
    @config {string} [setting2] An optional setting.
    @params {MyClass~FuncCallback} callback The callback function
*/
function(parameters, callback) {
    // ...
};

/**
 * This callback is displayed as part of the MyClass class.
 * @callback MyClass~FuncCallback
 * @param {number} responseCode
 * @param {string} responseMessage
 */
```

Comment: Can you point to the documentation for the `@config` tag? I found [nothing on usejsdoc.org](https://www.google.com/search?q=%40config+site%3Ausejsdoc.org), and [this page](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/DocExamples) suggests `@config` has been deprecated.

Comment: I think `@config` is deprecated at this point. [YUIDoc recommends using `@attribute` instead.](https://yui.github.io/yuidoc/syntax/index.html)