# JSDoc: How do I document the "options" object literal for a parent "class"?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am using jQuery's `$.widget()` base "class" which provides an `option()` method. Since the method is not in my code, I don't have a place to document the argument.

I tried to put jsDoc on the fields in the default options literal, but they're simply not picked up. Then I tried to use the `@class` and `@lends` tags on the same object literal, but this may be quite confusing as the object literal is not really a class.

Another alternative I've experimented is to put something like `@param options.field description` in the constructor's jsDoc. However, this has the disadvantage of separating the documentation from the code. Also, the constructor don't actually have an argument called `options` as it's all handled by jQuery.

How does you Javascript gurus handle this? Should a new tag be proposed?

Comment: Your question sounds very similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460604/how-to-describe-object-arguments-in-jsdoc

Comment: @LeviHackwith Yes, it is similar, but as I have described in the question it iself, I don't have a place where I can use the @param tag because the jQuery guys have implemented all the boiler plate code (including the `options()` function where the @param tag would normally be used.)

Comment: [`/** @param {Object.<string,*>} options */`](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/contrib/externs/jquery-1.7.js) seems to be one way to do it.

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate to the linked question as this is specific to jQuery Widgets. I have the same problem and have reasoned that since the options are usually (at least in our case) specified when instantiating the widget, I put the @param {Object} [options] as seen in the answer below at the widget declaration $.widget("myWidget", { ... })

Answer (score 104):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a function that takes an options object and you want to document all of its members?

A rough example of how to do that in JSDoc is as below:

```
/**
 * @description
 * Compliment someone on their something.
 *
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {String} options.name    A person's name
 * @param {String} options.feature A person's property
 */
function flatter (options) {
  options = options || {};
  console.log('%s, loving your %s!', options.name, options.feature);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to document a property that has a space in it, e.g. `options['some property']`?

Comment: Not something I've tried, try a couple of variations of quoting the value and run the jsdoc generator to see. Please let us all know after.

Comment: Well since this question kept get bumped, I'll just clarify here: this is not the answer for my specific quesiton because as I've said, jQuery provides the "option" method so I do not have a method where the options literal is the argument.

Comment: @fold_left do we actually need @description? Never saw it being used. When I see it it is assumed that the first line is the description.

Comment: You're right about that @pcatre, I tend to use it anyway because it suits my preference but it can be omitted without issue.