# How should I comment object structure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, comments

I am using the following syntax to comment my code,

```
/*
 * @param variableName {variableType} Description
 * @return {returnType} Description
 */
```

But I now don't know how to comment my code for a constructor of one of my objects as the parameter is an object and that object's dictionary key is a parameter in itself as well as the value of that key.

My structure for the parameter is like below;

```
assets: {

    fruits: {

        rootPath: "files/fruits/",

        images: {

            apple: "apple.png",
            kiwi: "kiwi.png",
            orange: "orange.png",
            peach: "peach.png",
            pear: "pear.png",
            strawberry: "strawberry.png",
            watermelon: "watermelon.png"
        }
    },
    humans: {

        audio: {

            atari: "http://www.universal-soundbank.com/mp3/sounds/18534.mp3"
        }
    }
}
```

I have started by commenting that assets is an object:

```
@param assets {Object}
```

But how do I then go on to comment that the properties of assets is a value in itself? I understand this question may be a little off-topic, but I just want to make sure that my code comments conform to some kind of syntax rule and I haven't been able to find anything on this matter.

Comment: I don't know what JSDoc is, I have kinda made this pattern up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to describe "object" arguments in jsdoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460604/how-to-describe-object-arguments-in-jsdoc)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most informative is to enumerate all object properties as separate parameters. [Bracket] optional properties, e.g:

```
/**
 *
 * @param {Object} assets Description
 * @param {Object} assets.fruits Description
 * @param {Object} assets.fruits.rootPath Description
 * @param {Object} assets.fruits.images Description
 * @param {Object} [assets.humans] Description
 *
 */
```

See "Parameters with Properties" from [JSDoc](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagParam). Also [How to describe "object" arguments in jsdoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460604/how-to-describe-object-arguments-in-jsdoc).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JSDoc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc).  This is what you're looking for, I believe.  I use this in my projects and it follows closely to the same pattern as what you're using.  Except it has a tool that will generate documentation for you.

Here's the actual documentation: *[Use JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/)*

Answer (score 0):

The comment syntax that you are using looks a lot like [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/).

I am pretty sure. The [typedef](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html) tag looks appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps make the answer more affirmative? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)