# How to fight tons of unresolved variables warning in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I have a function that takes data from server:

```
function getData(data){
    console.log(data.someVar);
}
```

WebStorm says that `someVar` is an unresolved variable.
How can I get rid of such warnings?

I see several options:

- Suppress warnings in IDE settings;
- Add a JSON source file with fields ([details](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5366907));
- Use array-like syntax: `data['some_unres_var']`;

Also, WebStorm is offering me to create namespace for the "data" (add an annotation like `/** @namespace data.some_unres_var*/`), create such field, or rename it.

Comment: @hellboy Quick answer: right-click -> Use Javascript Library -> make sure HTML is checked. Follow this up by looking at the available javascript libraries in the project settings to get a better understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/):

```
/**
 * @param {{some_unres_var:string}} data
 */
function getData(data){
    console.log(data.some_unres_var);
}
```

Comment: For variables use this syntax
`/**
 * @type {Object}
 * @property {string} sortval - value to sort by
 */
var a;`

Comment: How would you do that when the function is an anonymouns function ? as in  ........ .then(function(data){ .... })

Comment: Is there a similar method to define global variables? I'm referencing an external library in my web app, I need to use stuff such as `MediumEditor`, but intellij gives me the infamous unresolved variable warning.

Comment: @borislemke: this answer won't work for variables that aren't parameters. The general solution is to [use @namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835544/how-to-fight-a-lots-of-unresolved-variables-warning-in-webstorm/44093516#44093516).

Answer (score 61):

JSDoc the object. Then its members.

```
/**
 * @param data          Information about the object.
 * @param data.member   Information about the object's members.
 */
function getData(data){
    console.log(data.member);
}
```

- `@property` for local variables (non parameters).
- Tested in PyCharm. @Nicholi confirms it works in WebStorm.
- The `{{ member:type }}` syntax Andreas suggested may conflict with Django templates.
- Thanks to Jonny Buchanan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6460748/673991) citing the [@param wiki](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagParam).

To document **arrays of objects**, use `[]` brackets as JSDoc [suggests](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties):

```
/**
 * @param data
 * @param data.array_member[].foo
 */
```

Comment: What about variables that aren't parameters? The general solution is to [use @namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835544/how-to-fight-a-lots-of-unresolved-variables-warning-in-webstorm/44093516#44093516).

Answer (score 33):

All other answers are incorrect for the general case. What if you don't get `data` as a parameter? You don't have JSDoc then:

```
function niceApiCall(parameters) {
  const result = await ...  // HTTP call to the API here
  for (const e of result.entries) {
    .. // decorate each entry in the result
  }
  return result;
}
```

WebStorm will warn that "result.entries" is an unresolved variable (field).

The general solution is to add an `@namespace` declaration:

```
function niceApiCall(parameters) {
  /** @namespace result.entries **/
  const result = await ...  // HTTP call to the API here
  for (const e of result.entries) {
    .. // decorate each entry in the result
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I have many attributes returned from an API so using your technique I presume I would need to list the lot of them to avoid the errors I'm seeing like this:

```
    /** @namespace req.headers.signaturecertchainurl **/
    /** @namespace req.headers.signature **/
     /** @namespace req.headers.slots **/
     /** @namespace req.headers.nutrientslot **/
 ```
Is there a way to create a higher level namespace (e.g. `req.headers`) and automagically assign children to it? (sorry for no formatting in comments!)

Comment: Is this a webstorm specific solution or an editor standard solution? That's what I'm still unsure of...

Comment: @philo.O: it's a JSDoc solution, which WebStorm parses. But using TypeScript avoids this problem altogether.

Comment: When using this solution, I am getting a `Unresolved variable or type 'entries'` message. How to fix this?

Answer (score 17):

Destructuring use, Luke.

```
function getData(data){
    const {member} = data;
    console.log(member);
}
```

Comment: To help with a complication I ran into, if the variable you're destructuring has an Eslint-illegal name like `my_var`, you can rename it: `const { my_var: myVar } = data`.

Answer (score 7):

using a dummy js file with anonymous function expression returning the json literal, as written at http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5366907, may be a solution. I can also suggest creating a fake variable that will hold this json value,  and use this var as a value of @param annotation to let WebStorm know what the  actual type is. Like:

```
var jsontext = {"some_unres_var":"val"};
/** @param {jsontext} data */
function getData(data){
    console.log(data.some_unres_var);
}
```

See also http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5504337#5504337

Comment: Elena's suggestion on the JetBrains forum is a [weird solution](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206349469/comments/115000258810). The general solution is to [use @namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835544/how-to-fight-a-lots-of-unresolved-variables-warning-in-webstorm/44093516#44093516).

Answer (score 4):

To remove the warnings on The WebStorm IDE you can simply uncheck the inspection options for:

- **Unresolved Javascript function**
- **Unresolved Javascript variable**

**ps. this will remove the warnings on the IDE, that I don't think  is the best idea, because we will lost one of the best utilities in a IDE like Webstorm, which can worsen the quality of our code.**

Even so, if you want to follow in the menu: ***File*** > ***Settings*** > ***Editor*** > ***Inspections*** we can disable the Javascript warnings

Like the following picture:

[image: uncheck options]

Answer (score 2):

## Tons of "unresolved variables" when using `"moduleResolution": "bundler"` in the `tsconfig.json`

I ran into a similar issue when porting a `React` app to `NextJs`.
The fact is that modern `NextJs` suggests using `"moduleResolution": "bundler"` in the `tsconfig.json` configuration file, but this causes an error in the `webstorm`.

If you're facing a similar issue, try changing `moduleResolution` to `node`.

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* ... */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    /* ... */
  },
 /* ... */
}
```