# Correct way to avoid 'Unresolved variable ...' errors when using variables returned as a JSON object from an API

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I'm trying to clean up some legacy JS code in WebStorm and have a series of errors when I inspect the code which take the format:
`Unresolved variable varFromJson`.

I'm using a 3rd party API to retrieve a JSON object and I'm assigning some values held in returned JSON key-value pairs to local variables. The code works fine but I'd like to clean up the inspection errors. So, I Googled and found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44093516/131385) from [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu) which suggests that using

`/** @namespace varFromJson **/`

is the correct way to do things but everyone else suggests using

`/** @param varFromJson **/`.

So, simply how should I declare my list of variables that will be coming from the external JSON file?

---

A snippet of the returned JSON file's structure is:

```
{
  "body": {
    "food": [
      {
        "name": "beans",
        "weight": "200g",
        "code": "hz168"
      },
      {
        "name": "apple",
        "weight": "180g",
        "code": "fv21"
      }
    ],
    "store": {
      "name": "Blooms",
      "city": "New York"
    }
  }
}
```

---

I'm using a lot of values from the returned JSON so avoiding repetition would be good. Given the above structure, is there a way to declare a "parent" node making all of its children resolve? I presumed that was what the `@namespace` tag did.

Comment: The comment you linked to indicates a different usage. If it's a parameter, use the standard `@param` approach. If it isn't a parameter, `@namespace` should work. `@param` is always correct when it's a parameter. `@namespace` is, arguably, incorrect unless it is in fact a namespace although it will work for values collected through a statement.

Comment: @MikeC Thanks. I'm confused as to when to use `/** @param **/` vs `/** @namespace **/` I'd read the "if it's a parameter" logic on the other question (and read the JSDoc docs) but I'm afraid I don't understand "a parameter of what?"...I appreciate I'm being thick about this but I'm confused!

Comment: It means a parameter of a function. For example, `x` is a parameter of `function(x) { .. }`.

Comment: Thanks - I've got that but the higher level resp is all that's passed as a parameter to the function. Say I've got code that has a function in which the request is initiated: `function getData(req, resp){}` then I guess I can declare the `/** @param resp **/` here. However, I don't pass `resp.body.store.name` as a parameter directly - only the whole response.

Comment: Right, so you do like they stated in the other question. You declare `resp` as a `@param` and give it a type which has the properties you're looking for.

Comment: @MikeC thanks...I'll explore that approach.