# Copy value from input field

Tags: javascript, html

I need to copy the value from the input field to the clipboard. Instead of getting the value of the input field I get null.

Here is my Code:

```html
<input type="text" value=${model.anchor_url} id=${properties.anchor_name}>
<button class="c-button" onclick="myFunction()">
    <span class="c-button__label">Copy</span>
</button>
<div data-sly-test="${model.anchor_url}">
    <p>URL from Model :</p>
    <pre>${model.anchor_url}</pre>
</div>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    const field = document.getElementById(`${properties.anchor_name}`);
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(field);
    alert("Copied the text to clipboard: " + field);
}
```

The value for `field` variable results null even though the id exist and it has a value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: What is the value of `properties.anchor_name`? It looks like you've used the string `${properties.anchor_name}` as the ID of an input, rather than the variable's value.

Comment: properties.anchor_name is a variable and it has a value eg. Anchor1. I am not sure if that is what you asked.

Comment: `document.getElementById(properties.anchor_name)` should be your selector. There is no use for template literals here.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your suggestion @Lain since ${properties.anchor_name} is a String value.

Comment: @Anuska In simple terms he is saying you don't need to put `$[}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. It appears due to cross site scripting prevention JS can not be executed from html for the site I develop but has to be built using TypeScript.

Comment: How can TypeScript be executed but JavaScript can not?

Comment: I found out AEM JavaScript is loaded through clientlibs https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/introduction/clientlibs.html?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

You get an Object with this line: `document.getElementById(`${properties.anchor_name}`)`. With the parameter `value` you will get the value from the input field.

So you have to try:

```
const field = document.getElementById(`${properties.anchor_name}`).value;
```

Comment: When I try as you suggested IntelliJ gives me a warning "Unresolved variable value" for .value

Comment: @Anuska that is up to InteliJ itself. You can 
`/**
 * @param {{some_unres_var:string}} data
 */` suppress the message. Found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835544/how-to-fight-tons-of-unresolved-variables-warning-in-webstorm

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to copy the element, instead of it's Value, you have to get it's Value using `element.value`, also if the value of `field` variable is null, this means the Element you are trying to get doesn't exist with that Element ID

And also, you were trying to copy the whole element instead of it's value, So Replace the first line in your function with this one:

```js
const field = document.getElementById(properties.anchor_name).value;
```

Also there is no need to put template literals in your code as you can do so without that too!

For example assume there is a variable `element_ID` which can be written in JS like this:

```
var element_ID = "myInput"
```

now i want to get that Element, so I can just directly do this:

```
document.getElementById(element_ID)
```

instead of this:

```
document.getElementById(`${element_ID}`)
```

Comment: When I do it like you suggested I get in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getElementById' on 'Document': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.`

Comment: Sorry by mistake it was the wrong command, try this out ```document.getElementById(`${properties.anchor_name}`)```

Comment: No problem. That is when I get null for the field.

Comment: This means you are trying to get an invalid element, the function `getElementById` returns null when it can't find the element, so check that you're trying to get the right element