# JSDoc how to add any additional properties of an Object?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a JSDoc comment of a typedef like below,

```js
/**
 * Lorem ipsum dolor...
 * @typedef {Object} NotificationOptions
 * @property {boolean} foo - Property 1
 * @property {boolean} bar - Property 2
 */
```

How to add any additional properties to the object besides foo and bar? (the property can be anything with any type, thus the type is flexible)

I had an example on typescript interface definition like below. I wanted my JSDoc to have similar effect with this interface definition on TS.

```js
export interface FooBar {
  foo: boolean;
  bar: boolean;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

I know it is optional and the code can run buttery smooth without the typedef. Just curious and wanted to had a clean and good code.

Thank you!

Comment: This might be relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460604/how-to-describe-object-arguments-in-jsdoc

Comment: @lux, no it's not